# Transacción Insert con If Else SQL y C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy desarrollando un programa donde envío un activo que puede o no estar asociado a una habitación. Si no se asocia a una habitación idHabitación = 0, si no contiene la clave primaria de esa habitación. Creé un procedimiento donde valido primero si el activo existe con el número de serie, si no existe, valido si idHabitacion es 0, si lo es hace un insert sin llenar el campo idHabitacion (null), sino si lo llena (llave primaria), pero esto no me está funcionando.

```
create proc procCrearNuevoActivoPagNuevoActivo
@nomActivo varchar(255),
@numSerie as varchar(255),
@idTipo  int,
@marcaActivo varchar(255), 
@modeloActivo varchar(255),
@fechaCompra date,
@fechaVenceGarantia date,
@estadoActivo varchar(255),
@descripcion text,
@idUsuario int,
@idHabitacion int
as 
if (not exists(select * from IH_ACTIVOS where numSerie=@numSerie))
    begin 
        if (@idHabitacion=0)
        begin 
            insert into IH_ACTIVOS(nomActivo, fechaCreacion, numSerie, idTipos, marcaActivo, modeloActivo, 
            fechaCompra, fechaVenceGarantia,estadoActivo, descripcion, idUsuario) 
            values(@nomActivo,GETDATE(),@numSerie,@idTipo,@marcaActivo, @modeloActivo,
            @fechaCompra,@fechaVenceGarantia,@estadoActivo,@descripcion,@idUsuario)
        end
            else
                begin
                    insert into IH_ACTIVOS(nomActivo, fechaCreacion, numSerie, idTipos, marcaActivo, modeloActivo, 
                    fechaCompra, fechaVenceGarantia,estadoActivo, descripcion, idUsuario, idHabitacion) 
                    values(@nomActivo,GETDATE(),@numSerie,@idTipo,@marcaActivo, @modeloActivo,
                    @fechaCompra,@fechaVenceGarantia,@estadoActivo,@descripcion,@idUsuario, @idHabitacion)
                end
    end
```

C#:

```
 public string procCrearNuevoActivoPagNuevoActivo(Activo objActivo)
        {
            string mensaje = "";
            cn = conexion.getConexion();

            using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("procCrearNuevoActivoPagNuevoActivo", cn, tr);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("nomActivo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objActivo.nomActivo;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("numSerie", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objActivo.numSerie;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("idTipo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objActivo.idTipo;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("marcaActivo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objActivo.marcaActivo;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("modeloActivo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objActivo.modeloActivo;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("fechaCompra", SqlDbType.Date).Value = objActivo.fechaCompra;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("fechaVenceGarantia", SqlDbType.Date).Value = objActivo.fechaVenceGarantia;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("estadoActivo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = objActivo.estadoActivo;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("descripcion", SqlDbType.Text).Value = objActivo.descripcion;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("idHabitacion", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objActivo.idHabitacion;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("idUsuario", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objActivo.idUsuario;

                try
                {
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (i== 1)
                    {
                        mensaje = "Se ingresó " + i + " nuevo activo";
                        tr.Commit();
                    }
                    else {
                        mensaje = "El número de serie " + objActivo.numSerie + " ya existe en inventario !";
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    mensaje = "Error en el registro del activo: "+e;
                    tr.Rollback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
                return mensaje;
            }
        }
```

Diagrama:

[image: Diagrama de las tablas]

Lo que quiero en el procedimiento almacenado es básicamente:
" SI Activo no existe entonces, si idHabitacion=0 entonces inserte todo menos idHabitación (queda null), sino entonces inserte todo (con idHabitaion = valor correspondiente).

El problema es que cuando guardo un activo con un nuevo número de serie, por ejemplo sk123, este se guarda pero me indica que "El número de serie  sk123 ya existe en inventario !" en lugar de dicirme "Se ingresó 1 nuevo activo" que sería lo correcto.
Lo que creo que pasa es que se están ejecutando ambos update y no está obedeciendo los If Else que puse para validar @idHabitacion.

A veces me pasa que aparece un mensaje de interbloqueo lo cual no debería pasar, lo que me hace pensar que se ejecutan ambos update.

Quedo atento. Gracias !

Comment: Recomendación: La lógica que está en tu base de datos, pásala a la capa de negocios, el motivo es mantener la sencillez del desarrollo. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Dejando de lado la pésima idea de pasar toda la lógica a la "capa de negocios", te recomiendo que no confíes en el conteo de filas ya que puede tener inconsistencias en su comportamiento. De hecho, la recomendación general es deshabilitar el conteo de filas al momento de llamar los procedimientos desde la aplicación mediante el uso de `SET NOCOUNT ON`. Una opción que tienes, es la de generar un error desde tu procedimiento que sea capturado por el TRY de tu código en C#.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procCrearNuevoActivoPagNuevoActivo(
    @nomActivo varchar(255),
    @numSerie as varchar(255),
    @idTipo  int,
    @marcaActivo varchar(255), 
    @modeloActivo varchar(255),
    @fechaCompra date,
    @fechaVenceGarantia date,
    @estadoActivo varchar(255),
    @descripcion text,
    @idUsuario int,
    @idHabitacion int
)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM IH_ACTIVOS WHERE numSerie = @numSerie))
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO IH_ACTIVOS(
            nomActivo, 
            fechaCreacion, 
            numSerie, 
            idTipos, 
            marcaActivo, 
            modeloActivo, 
            fechaCompra, 
            fechaVenceGarantia,
            estadoActivo, 
            descripcion, 
            idUsuario,
            idHabitacion
    ) 
    VALUES(
            @nomActivo,
            GETDATE(),
            @numSerie,
            @idTipo,
            @marcaActivo, 
            @modeloActivo,
            @fechaCompra,
            @fechaVenceGarantia,
            @estadoActivo,
            @descripcion,
            @idUsuario,
            NULLIF( @idHabitacion, 0)
    );
END
ELSE
    RAISERROR(  '¡El número de serie %s ya existe en inventario !', 11, 1, @numSerie);
GO
```

No tengas miedo de usar espacio suficiente para mejorar la lectura de tus procedimientos almacenados. También recuerda utiliza el principio DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself / No te repitas).

Aun mejor, sería que la tabla IH_ACTIVOS tuviera un `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` en la columna numSerie para no necesitar la validación inicial y todo quedaría en un simple `INSERT` y capturas el error para regresar el mensaje deseado en vez del mensaje por default.

```
ALTER TABLE IH_ACTIVOS ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_IH_ACTIVOS_NumSerie UNIQUE ( numSerie);
```

Comment: Esto me sirve para validar la existencia del activo, pero no si voy a ingresar con un valor de idHabitacion o no. La idea es que si {@idHabitacion = 0} se ejecute un insert sin el campo @idHabitación, de lo contrario, que sí lo tome en cuenta.

Comment: Eso mismo hace. La función NULLIF convertirá el zero en un nulo. Así será como si no insertaras nada sin necesidad de un IF.

Comment: En este caso Luis, ¿ Cómo puedo interpretar la ejecución correcta del procedimiento en C# para saber que sí se agregó el activo correctamente?

Comment: Si no genera ningún error, entonces se agregó correctamente. Alternativamente, puedes usar el comando RETURN después del INSERT para regresar @@ROWCOUNT. Ejemplo: `RETURN @@ROWCOUNT;`. O también puedes utilizar un parámetro con OUTPUT para regresar algún valor  de cualquier tipo (RETURN solo maneja enteros).

Comment: Pero entonces en el C# puedo seguir utilizando cmd.ExcecuteNonQuery() para validar el correcto ingreso del dato ? o como sería si quiero devolver un mensaje con output para leerlo en C#.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres validar? Si envías la instrucción para que se inserte una fila, eso se va a hacer. Si no lo hace, va a regresar un error. De ninguna forma va a insertar más de una fila y si no cumple con la condición del IF, entonces va a generar un error por medio del RAISERROR(). El error lo capturas en C# con TRY y ahí regresas el mensaje que deseas.

Comment: Me da este error:  Error en el registro del activo: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): ¡El número de serie 3333 ya existe en inventario ! en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) en ... Cuando guardo el dato en C# con  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), lo raro es que el dato sí se guarda en la BD, como si estuviera haciendo caso omiso al if y al else y todo fuera un solo bloque de código. Utilizo el mismo procedimiento y el campo numSerie es unique.

Comment: Quieres decir que el número de serie 3333 está en la BD 2 veces? Si está sólo una es porque está realizando la validación y está regresando el error a la aplicación que se tendría que capturar en el TRY.

Comment: El problema es que coloqué Scrip Manager para restringir los campos del formulario y esto causaba las inconsistencias. Cuando agregaba un nuevo activo con numSerie distinto me aparecía que ya estaba en la BD, siendo un nuevo valor, y aún así lo agregaba. Quité el Scrip Manager impedía el post del formulario.